# Protecting a flatfile database

Tags: php, database, security

I am attempting to protect a flatfile database from being accessed or queried by anyone except PHP running from my server.

Google has a lot of very broad theory but nothing solid in terms of processes on a webserver to secure the data. It cannot be contained above the web root.

Comment: Are you asking about setting file permissions?

Comment: Or just `<FilesMatch>` and `Deny from All`

Comment: @mobius I'm asking how to prevent anyone but local PHP accessing a file in my accessible root, if possible with permissions go ahead. @mario I have looked into `.htaccess` protection but I read somewhere that `.htaccess` isn't 100% reliable because the file can sometimes be skipped... not sure about the authenticity of that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .htaccess:

```
<Files *.db>
Deny from All
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I write that so that instead of searching for the file it becomes a rule for all files with a `.db` extension? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an entire directory inaccessible from the web by using `.htaccess`, similar to above, but I would make a separate directory for these and disallow the whole thing:

```
<Directory ~ "db">
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

This will obviously disallow any files you put in the "db" directory from your webroot.

Answer (score 1):

That "must be contained inside web root" restriction could be a problem; it's certainly not ideal.

My suggestion would be to ask over at [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) regarding how to configure the web server to disallow access to this file (don't trust programmers when you don't have to), but also keep in mind that you have to ensure there's no way to display the contents of the file through a script.

Also: **if there is any chance at all that you will be running scripts that display the contents of files¹**, you have to special-case the code that does so to explicitly prevent it from operating on your database file. This can only be done on a case-by-case basis, and it's something that you have to always keep in mind (code with this functionality may be added in the future). Not an enviable situation.

¹*This is easier to than you may think: even something as "simple" as `include($view)` where `$view` can be supplied from the URL and is not properly validated can do the damage.*